# Struts 1 - How to display ActionMessages

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I am displaying `ActionMessage`s through a `JSP` file by the following command:

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
    <ul id="messsages">
        <html:messages id="msg" message="true">
            <li><bean:write name="msg"/> </li>
        </html:messages>
    </ul>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Now I want to display only selected messages. How can I indicate which message to display?

### Updated

Actually I have two `ActionMessages` object - `messages` and `warnings`.
Now I want to display both of them on separate `JSP` page... One page to show `messages` and other for `warnings`.

So how to indicate in the `JSP` page that which messages to display?

### Updated - 2

Now, I found a strange thing.

```
saveMessages(request, messages);
saveMessages(request, warnings);
```

When I wrote the above code, only `warnings` was working. When I reversed the order of the above two statements, then only `messages` was working.

It seems that we can add only one `ActionMessages` object in a request. If it is correct, then how to display messages in two `ActionMessages` objects seperately.

Comment: the Globals.XXX_KEY constants are stored **once** on request or session. Hence why you find your methods strange.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple,

Separate your `messages` and your `warnings`: In your struts action, save your messages and warnings as follows:

```
//For messages
saveMessages(request, messages);

//For warnings
saveErrors(request, warnings);
```

To display them:

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
    <html:messages id="aMsg" message="true">
        <logic:present name="aMsg">
            <!-- Messages -->
            <div class="messages">
                <bean:write name="aMsg" filter="false" />
            </div>
        </logic:present>
    </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>

<logic:messagesPresent message="false">
    <html:messages id="aMsg" message="false">
        <logic:present name="aMsg">
            <!-- Warnings-->
            <div class="warnings">
                <bean:write name="aMsg" filter="false" />
            </div>
        </logic:present>
    </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

This displays all `messages` (by setting `message="true"`)

```
<html:messages id="aMsg" message="true">
```

This displays all `warnings` (by setting `message="false"`)

```
<html:messages id="aMsg" message="false">
```

**UPDATE** Seeing that you're now clearing your question, the simplest way would be to do this.

Have a certain flag that will indicate whether the user would like to view `messages` or `warnings`. On the Struts Action, request the flag and check if the user selected viewing messages or warnings.
You then save either `warnings` or `messages` based on the user selection and display the same page (as you wrote above) to display messages.

The reason is this, Struts (when storing you messages or errors) stores it on request or session with the following constant.

- Globals.MESSAGE_KEY (that is assigned when you do `saveMessages(request, messages)`)
- Globals.ERROR_KEY (that is assigned when you do `saveErrors(request, errors)`)

when using `<logic:messagesPresent message="true">`, Struts searches for the `MESSAGE_KEY` (if message=true) or `ERROR_KEY` (if message=false) or both (if message=none). You have no control of that.

`<html:messages />` TLD comments states:

> By default the tag will retrieve the
>   bean it will iterate   over from the
>   Globals.ERROR_KEY constant string,
>   but if this attribute is set to 'true'
>   the bean will be   retrieved from the
>   Globals.MESSAGE_KEY constant   string.
>   Also if this is set to 'true', any
>   value assigned   to the name attribute
>   will be ignored.

You can also write scriptlet to check if those keys exists, then `<logic:iterate />` through the key to display the messages (but that'll be too much work).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `message` attribute on the `messagesPresent` and `messages` tags, you can use the `name` attribute to specify the name of the ActionMessages object you have in page, request, session, or application scope.

Comment: can I also select particular messages from a ActionMessages object?

Comment: You can select particular messages by property using the `property` attribute.  Other than that, I think you'd have to iterate the ActionMessages yourself.